# Ubuntu 21.10 Bluetooth issues

Tags: sound, bluetooth, 21.10

a couple days I updated to Ubuntu 21.10 and since then, Bluetooth has stopped working. It turns on fine on start up, and searches for devices, and I'm able to pair devices, but when I try to connect to a paired device, the toggle does not work.

It just says the connection is disabled, and won't connect.

Also, if I turn Bluetooth off, it won't turn on again unless I restart the computer.

I have deleted and re-installed Bluetooth, and tried all kinds of fixes suggested on the forums, but nothing works so far.

Comment: FYI:  Don't forget [Ubuntu 21.10 is in it's last day(s) of support](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/06/01/ubuntu-21-10-impish-indri-reaches-end-of-life-on-july-14-2022/); so plan your *release-upgrade* to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS before it's hours or EOL.

Comment: How do I upgrade to 22.04? My computer just suggested me to upgrade to 21.10 and so I did, now I'm regretting it. I got the Bluetooth toggle to work after installing bluez, so now it works, but I can't hear any sounds from my Bluetooth speakers. The speakers work fine connected to my phone, but with the Ubuntu there is no sound.

Comment: Did you look at the link I provided; it contained the [*how to*](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/JammyUpgrades) link within it.  "*The supported upgrade path from Ubuntu 21.10 is via Ubuntu 22.04. Instructions and caveats for the upgrade may be found at: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/JammyUpgrades  Ubuntu 22.04 continues to be actively supported with security updates and select high-impact bug fixes.*"

Comment: Thank you, I was able to get my computer to prompt it, and I have now updated to Ubuntu 22.04. I have a new problem however, the system has no sounds, and no way to control sound level.

Comment: Adjust this question to match your new system & details; or just delete this question & ask a new question.